# How to call another DetailView::widget from another model in one view YII2?

Tags: php, yii2

I am new in `yii2`. I have display data for a table in `DetailView::widget`.

I want to call another `DetailView::widget` for another table and display then in the same view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `DetailView` widgets in the same view, there is no problem.

In controller:

```
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

...

public function actionView($id)
{
    $model1 = $this->findModel($id);
    $model2 = ModelName::find()->where(['id' => ...])->one();
    if (!$model2) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Second model not found');
    }

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model1' => $model1,
        'model2' => $model2,
    ]);
}
```

In view:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model1,
        'attributes' => [
            'name',
        ],
    ]) ?>    
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <?= DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $model2,
        'attributes' => [
            'name',
        ],
    ]) ?>
</div>
```

[More](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html) info on `DetailView` widget.